# Azure deploy from several repositories in one website

Tags: git, azure

I have several websites in bitbucket each is in its own repository. They all are dependant on another repository called "core" which do things like bootstrapping each website. This works very well on my local machine since the folder structure is something like

```
/website1 // includes core
/website2 // includes core
/core
```

The website1 and website2 repositories are correctly deployed, but they are dependant on the core repository.

However, in Azure deployment you can only link one repository to each website.

What are the best approach in this case? Ideally i want to link two repositories both website and core to a deploy.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours i found out that Azure respects submodules. So for me the solution was to add the core repository as a submodule and change the behaviour on how i loaded the core. 
So with:

```
git submodule add <repo>
```

it all deployed fine!